# How do I get the dependencies for a given project in Gradle code?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, jnlp

EDIT

In our build process, we build a handful of apps that are webstart apps.  Each of these projects has a pom and is built with Maven.  The next step in the build process is to build the webapp which contains the jnlps and jars for each of these apps.  I am trying to build the jnlps and webapp that holds everything in Gradle, because Gradle gives me more flexibility.  In our previous build system, everything was done in Ant.

I want to create one gradle script which will generate the jnlp files for each project.  I would like to create a list of the webstart apps like the following

```
projects = ['com.company:project1:1.0', 
            'com.company:project2:1.0', 
            'com.company:project3:1.0']
```

and then loop through each project,and then iterate through through each dependency to generate the xml for the project which will look something like this:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase = "..." href="...">
    <!-- Other stuff goes here -->
    <resources> 
        <jar href="lib/jython-2.5.3.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar"/>
        <!--- Other dependencies go here --->
    </resources>
</jnlp>
```

How do I iterate through the dependencies of a list of projects in gradle code?  In pseudo code, I want to do something like this:

```
projects = ['com.company:project1:1.0', 
            'com.company:project2:1.0', 
            'com.company:project3:1.0']

for (project: projects) {
    def fileName = "$project.name().jnlp"
    File file = new File (fileName)
    for (dependency: project) {
        file.writeln("<jar href=\"lib/$dependency.fileName\"/>") 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not clarify the way you declare your lists of projects.
Gradle can resolve your dependencies, if all your project configurations are visible for him.
That means you need to have gradle build for each project, which dependencies you want to print.

According to your question, you can define each project as a single java module, for example in our project we have structure like this

```
-our_project[our-project]
   -modules (folder)
       -core   [our-project-core]   (java module)
       -web    [our-project-web]    (java module)
       -portal [our-project-portal] (java module)
   -build.gradle
   -settings.gradle
   -gradle.properties
```

Each module has its own gradle configuration.

This is content of settings.gradle file

```
rootProject.name = 'our-project'
include(':our-project-core', ':our-project-web', ':our_project-portal')
project(':our-project-core').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'modules/core')
project(':our-project-web').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'modules/web')
project(':our-project-portal').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'modules/portal')
```

And the content of build.gradle in this case will be:

```
....
def coreModule = project(':our-project-core')
def webModule = project(':our-project-web')
def portalModule = project(':our-project-portal')

configure(coreModule) {
    //core module configurations here like
    dependencies {
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.4") //for example
    ....
    }
}

configuration(webModule) {
    //
}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the project has the `java` plugin applied:

```
for (file in project.configurations.runtime) {
    println file
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  How do I convert 'com.company:project1:1.0' to a project object?.  I have 4 or 5 of these jnlp's I want to build, and I want to do them all in the same gradle file, because they all go into the same web app.

Comment: It's easier to start with the `Project` object(s) right away.

Comment: Can I define 5 different projects in my gradle file since I have 5 different sets of dependencies?

Comment: Not sure if understood the question well but basically single `build.gradle` file is a single `project`.